# How to get parent folder in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to insert images, css and js dynamic. I have a folder themes and there I want to have multiple themes.

Below the structure of my app. This themes folder is located in the root.

[image: Structure]

I have added this record in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(css|js|img)/(.*)$ /themes/default/$1/$2
```

And my path will be redirected like:

```
/css/style.css             http://site.com/themes/default/css/style.css
/js/someLib.js             http://site.com/themes/default/js/someLib.js
/img/background.jpg        http://site.com/themes/default/img/background.jpg
```

Now I want the `default` directory to be dynamic.

I tried something like this

```
RewriteRule ^(css|js|img)/(.*)$ ../$1/$2
```

And I tried

```
/default/css/style.css
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(css|js|img)/(.*)$ /themes/$1/$2/$3
```

But without result :(

Comment: Strange it doesnt work... try with `RewriteRule ^(.+)?/(css|js|img)/(.+)$ /themes/$1/$2/$3`. The `?` makes it stop as soon as it finds the first slash, maybe that's the problem with `(.*)`.

Comment: @PaoloStefan Thanks, but it resulted in a `500 internal server error`. Maybe I need something with the `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}/(.+)/(css|js|img)` but I don't know how to use it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/((?:css|js|img)/.+)$ /themes/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```